# Interprocess message broadcast

Tags: c#, .net, ipc

I need to broadcast messages from one process to other processes on the same machine. Reliability is not really important and message frequency is low. Message size is low (basically it consists of some classes with 2-3 properties).

When I say broadcast, it's like UDP broadcast. The server sends a message without any knowledge of listeners.

Is there any good protocol to do this or am I stuck with a WCF Named Pipe PubSub style solution?

Comment: I assume you're eluding to MSMQ being too robust?

Comment: If these will always be on the same machine you can look at named pipes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You could even use signalr with owin.

Comment: I have started using [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/), which is pretty much designed to work with the pub-sub model in the way you are talking about. I am still learning about it, but I have read it allows for in-memory queues which are transient in nature. It was pretty easy for me to set up my first tests, so I would recommend giving it a shot. [tag:masstransit]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following Matthew's advice and implemented a simple service bus with SignalR.